# Understanding Cryptography practically

Tags: reference-request

I have just undergone a one semester course in cryptography. I was introduced to multiple theoretical aspects, the way several algorithms work, the methods and their stability and so on. Due to time constraint, not much of problem solving was done. I want to understand more of cryptography through practical problems. How do I go about it ? Relevant web sites can also be included. Thanks !!

Comment: Read this site and Security.SE often. You'll learn a ton. That said, this sort of a question is off-topic here as it is more of a discussion. Our chat room is not very active. You could ask on there and may get some info. The chat room on Security.SE is much more active and you should get some good info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really interested in practical problems and want to know what people care about when actually deploying crypto in practice, then you can start by e.g. reading through the messages of the IETF Crypto Forum Research Group mailing list. The discussions cover mostly crypto standards, which means that it's as practical as it can get. Archived discussions can be found here:

http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.ietf.irtf.cfrg

You won't find any homework problems there, but you can find discussions that will lead up to future standards.